# Click countries name and save opened Activity, every time open app , show to last selected countries activity, i want to add change the countries

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

There is a lot of countries in this app including India, Pakistan, UAE, South Africa..etc. When clicking on name of a country, a new activity will be opened. It will be saved by share preference and when we open the app, the last activity will be opened. I created an app like this. I want to add one more thing to this app.

I want to go to countries  list view by a button from the opened activity. The user can change the country here and when opening the app, the changed country's activity must be opened. If all countries are opened like this, there must be a option for choosing another country. I hope you will do this for me.

The project code which is done by me is given below.

The share preference will work on it. I want an option to change the country option.

**  countries Listview (MainActivity)**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CardView ind,pak,uae,south;
    String clickedCard;
    SharedPreferences prefs;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        ind = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.ind);
        pak = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.pak);

        ind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent CltButton = new Intent(MainActivity.this, India.class);
                clickedCard = "Button 1";
                CltButton.putExtra("fromMain", clickedCard);
                startActivity(CltButton);

            }

        });    

        pak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mgButton = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Pak .class);
                clickedCard = "Button 2";
                mgButton.putExtra("fromMain2", clickedCard);
                startActivity(mgButton);    

            }

        });               

    }

    private void checkPreferences() {

        ////INDIA Preference    
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (prefs.getString("txt", "").equals("") || prefs.getString("lastActivity", "").equals("")) {

        } else {    
            String txt = prefs.getString("txt", "");
            String activity = prefs.getString("lastActivity", "");
            Intent CltButton = new Intent(MainActivity.this, India.class);
            CltButton.putExtra("fromMain", txt);
            startActivity(CltButton);
            finish();
        }


        ////PAKISTAN Preference       
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref2", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (prefs.getString("txt2", "").equals("") || prefs.getString("lastActivity2", "").equals("")) {       

        } else {    
            String txt2 = prefs.getString("txt2", "");
            String activity = prefs.getString("lastActivity", "");
            Intent mgButton =MainActivity new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pak.class);
            mgButton.putExtra("fromMain2", txt2);
            startActivity(mgButton);
            finish();
        }

    }

}
```

**India Activity code**

```
   public class India extends AppCompatActivity {    
    String s;
    SharedPreferences prefs;    
    Button buttonind;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_india);

        buttonind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonind);

        buttonind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mgButton = new Intent(India.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(mgButton);

            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if (bundle == null) {
            s = "no data received";
        } else {
            s = bundle.getString("fromMain");
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();    
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("txt", s);
        editor.putString("lastActivity", getClass().getName());
        editor.apply();    
    }
}
```

**Pak Activity Code**

```
public class Pak extends AppCompatActivity {    
    String s;
    SharedPreferences prefs;   
    Button buttonpak;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pak);

        buttonpak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonpak);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if (bundle == null) {
            s = "no data received";
        } else {
            s = bundle.getString("fromMain2");
        }

        buttonpak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mgButton1 = new Intent(Pak.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(mgButton1);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref2", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("txt2", s);
        editor.putString("lastActivity2", getClass().getName());
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are the code for countrylist ? In which activity?

Comment: Mainactivity is countrylist  code

Comment: In which activity user can change country ?

Comment: india activity , and pak activity

Comment: Then you should create editText in both activity

Comment: please send sir this code me

Comment: I don't get you the logic

Comment: sir i a not prefesanal android develeper , i study the android developing in the youtube and stake overflow

Comment: I'm studying by myself too. How you want it to be implemented ? I don't get you.

Comment: any chance That would be okay

Comment: You may ask any developer who knows you

Comment: Add a button in both activity. When it pressed, they can select any countries they want to open. Does it make sense?

Comment: I used the introductory event in India and gave the connection to the miniseries (list view). Then what happens is that the application reopen, and the first selected activity itself becomes open.

I strive to try and look at what you do

Comment: In what activity

Comment: Both............

Comment: india and pak activty

Comment: post your latest code.

Comment: this is the latest code

Comment: Use my suggestions

Comment: you just add your suggestions , then you check, i dont understant it

Comment: add button in both activity.

Answer (score 0):

**You are very welcome for this** - It took me some time to do and it is working exactly like you want it to.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CardView ind,pak,uae,south;
String clickedCard;
SharedPreferences prefs;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    ind = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.ind);
    pak = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.pak);
    uae = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.uae);
    south = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.south);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if (bundle!= null) {
        SharedPreferences preferences,preferences1,preferences2,preferences3,preferences4;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor,editor1,editor2,editor3,editor4;
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
        preferences1 = getSharedPreferences("pref1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor1 = preferences1.edit();
        editor1.clear();
        editor1.apply();
        preferences2 = getSharedPreferences("pref2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor2 = preferences2.edit();
        editor2.clear();
        editor2.apply();
        preferences3 = getSharedPreferences("pref3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor3 = preferences3.edit();
        editor3.clear();
        editor3.apply();
        preferences4 = getSharedPreferences("pref4", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor4 = preferences4.edit();
        editor4.clear();
        editor4.apply();

    } else {
        checkPreferences();
    }

    //checkPreferences();

    ind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent CltButton = new Intent(MainActivity.this, India.class);
            clickedCard = "Button 1";
            CltButton.putExtra("fromMain", clickedCard);
            startActivity(CltButton);
            finish();


        }

    });


    pak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mgButton = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Pak.class);
            clickedCard = "Button 2";
            mgButton.putExtra("fromMain2", clickedCard);
            startActivity(mgButton);
            finish();


        }

    });

    uae.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent keraButton = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Uae.class);
            clickedCard = "Button 3";
            keraButton.putExtra("fromMain3", clickedCard);
            startActivity(keraButton);
            finish();

        }

    });

    south.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent ButtonactivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, South.class);
            clickedCard = "Button 4";
            ButtonactivityIntent.putExtra("fromMain4", clickedCard);
            startActivity(ButtonactivityIntent);
            finish();

        }

    });

}

private void checkPreferences() {


    ////INDIA Preference
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (prefs.getString("txt", "").equals("") || prefs.getString("lastActivity", "").equals("")) {


    } else {

        String txt = prefs.getString("txt", "");
        String activity = prefs.getString("lastActivity", "");
        Intent CltButton = new Intent(MainActivity.this, India.class);
        CltButton.putExtra("fromMain", txt);
        startActivity(CltButton);
        finish();
    }

    ////PAKISTAN Preference
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (prefs.getString("txt2", "").equals("") || prefs.getString("lastActivity2", "").equals("")) {


    } else {

        String txt2 = prefs.getString("txt2", "");
        String activity = prefs.getString("lastActivity", "");
        Intent mgButton = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pak.class);
        mgButton.putExtra("fromMain2", txt2);
        startActivity(mgButton);
        finish();
    }



    ////U A E Preference
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref3", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (prefs.getString("txt3", "").equals("") || prefs.getString("lastActivity3", "").equals("")) {


    } else {

        String txt2 = prefs.getString("txt3", "");
        String activity = prefs.getString("lastActivity", "");
        Intent mgButton = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Uae.class);
        mgButton.putExtra("fromMain3", txt2);
        startActivity(mgButton);
        finish();
    }


    //// SOUTH AFRICA Preference
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref4", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (prefs.getString("txt4", "").equals("") || prefs.getString("lastActivity4", "").equals("")) {


    } else {

        String txt2 = prefs.getString("txt4", "");
        String activity = prefs.getString("lastActivity", "");
        Intent mgButton = new Intent(MainActivity.this, South.class);
        mgButton.putExtra("fromMain4", txt2);
        startActivity(mgButton);
        finish();
    }
}

}
```

India.java:

```
public class India extends AppCompatActivity {

String s;
SharedPreferences prefs;

Button buttonind;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_india);

    buttonind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonind);

    buttonind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String test = "";
            Intent mgButton2 = new Intent(India.this, MainActivity.class);
            mgButton2.putExtra("test", test);
            startActivity(mgButton2);
            finish();

        }
    });

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if (bundle == null) {
        s = "no data received";
    } else {
        s = bundle.getString("fromMain");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("txt", s);
    editor.putString("lastActivity", getClass().getName());
    editor.apply();
}
}
```

Pakistan.java

```
public class Pak extends AppCompatActivity {

String s;
SharedPreferences prefs;

Button buttonpak;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pak);


    buttonpak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonpak);


    buttonpak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String test = "";
            Intent mgButton2 = new Intent(Pak.this, MainActivity.class);
            mgButton2.putExtra("test", test);
            startActivity(mgButton2);
            finish();


        }
    });

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if (bundle == null) {
        s = "no data received";
    } else {
        s = bundle.getString("fromMain2");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("txt2", s);
    editor.putString("lastActivity2", getClass().getName());
    editor.apply();
}
}
```

You can repeat the process for all the other countries. In `MainActivity` where I check `if (bundle!= null)` can be simplified, but it is working.